# Pandas: How to pivot/reshape a DataFrame they way I want (if it is possible...)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"date_id": ["2016-12-13", "2016-12-12", "2016-12-13", "2016-12-13", "2016-12-12"], "gender": ["female", "female", "male", "unisex", "male"], "value": [251, 302, 256, 23, 283]})
```

Which actually looks like this little friend:

```
      date_id  gender  value
0  2016-12-13  female    251
1  2016-12-12  female    302
2  2016-12-13    male    256
3  2016-12-13  unisex     23
4  2016-12-12    male    283
```

What I want is the following:

```
      date_id  female_value  male_value  unisex_value
0  2016-12-13           251         256            23
1  2016-12-12           302         283             0
```

Is it possible? If yes, which tool could make it happen? reshape? pivot?
Please be aware of that it should be python3.x compatible.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

**UPDATE**

I have to precise my question. In addition to the above stuff I want to transform my resulting dataframe with to_dict(orient="records") which looks like this:

```
df2.to_dict(orient="records")
[{'female_value': 251, 'date_id': '2016-12-13', 'male_value': 256, 'unisex_value': 23}, {'female_value': 302, 'date_id': '2016-12-12', 'male_value': 283, 'unisex_value': 0}]
```

Kind regards
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), but then is necessary [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and cast to `int`, last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='date_id', columns='gender', values='value')
       .fillna(0)
       .astype(int)
       .reset_index()
print (df)
gender     date_id  female  male  unisex
0       2016-12-12     302   283       0
1       2016-12-13     251   256      23
```

Another with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['date_id','gender']).value.unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
gender     date_id  female  male  unisex
0       2016-12-12     302   283       0
1       2016-12-13     251   256      23

print (df.to_dict(orient="records"))
[{'date_id': '2016-12-12', 'unisex': 0, 'female': 302, 'male': 283}, 
 {'date_id': '2016-12-13', 'unisex': 23, 'female': 251, 'male': 256}]
```

If need change column names add [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['date_id','gender']).value 
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .add_suffix('_value')
       .reset_index()
print (df)
gender     date_id  female_value  male_value  unisex_value
0       2016-12-12           302         283             0
1       2016-12-13           251         256            23

print (df.to_dict(orient="records"))
[{'female_value': 302, 'male_value': 283, 'unisex_value': 0}, 
 {'female_value': 251, 'male_value': 256, 'unisex_value': 23}]
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I had to precise my question (please see above). When I call to_dict(orient="records") on your resulting dataframe it does not ouput 'date_id' in the result.

Comment: Do you need change `male` to `male_value` and similar for another column names?

Comment: This actually seems to work. I will integrate it and when it works I will mark your answer as the kick-ass one :-). Many thanks so far